# ggpubr not recognizing ggplot objects

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggpubr to plot 2 plots but I get the error:

```
Error in ggplot_to_gtable(x) : 
  Argument needs to be of class "ggplot" or "gtable"
```

I need to use ggpubr because I want a shared legend.

```
library(ggpubr)
dat =data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
g1= ggplot(dat, aes(x =x , y = y))+geom_point()
g2= ggplot(dat, aes(x =x , y = y))+geom_point()
ggarrange(g1,g2, nrow = 1)
```

any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: It might be a bug. Without `nrow = 1` it works (or even trying something more than 1).

Comment: It does not work for me with nrow removed

Comment: `ggarrange(g1, g2)` with `ggpubr_0.1.6` works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you actually don't have any legends in the plots. Below I have created a legend for each plot with the `color` argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(ggpubr)
library(devtools)

# data
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
g1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(dat, aes(x = x , y = y, color = x)) + geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(dat, aes(x = x , y = y, color = x)) + geom_point()

# solution with ggpubr (note that I am leaving out nrow here because it doesn't work with that argument,
# so there might be indeed be a bug in this function; you should raise this on GitHub page for ggpubr)
ggpubr::ggarrange(g1, g2, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "right")
```

[image]

```r
# solution with cowplot (where you can specify nrow argument and it works)
prow <- cowplot::plot_grid(
  g1 + theme(legend.position = "none"),
  g2 + theme(legend.position = "none"),
  nrow = 1, 
  align = 'vh',
  labels = c("A", "B"),
  hjust = -1
)

legend <- cowplot::get_legend(g1)
cowplot::plot_grid( prow, legend, rel_widths = c(3, .3))
```

[image]

```r
# session info
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       America/New_York            
#>  date     2018-02-09
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version    date       source                          
#>  assertthat   0.2.0      2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  backports    1.1.2      2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  base       * 3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  bindr        0.1        2016-11-13 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  bindrcpp     0.2        2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  colorspace   1.3-2      2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  compiler     3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  cowplot    * 0.9.2      2017-12-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  datasets   * 3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  devtools   * 1.13.4     2017-11-09 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  digest       0.6.15     2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  dplyr        0.7.4      2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                  
#>  evaluate     0.10.1     2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  ggplot2    * 2.2.1      2016-12-30 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  ggpubr     * 0.1.6      2017-11-14 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  glue         1.2.0.9000 2018-01-05 Github (tidyverse/glue@1592ee1) 
#>  graphics   * 3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  grDevices  * 3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  grid         3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  gridExtra    2.3        2017-09-09 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                  
#>  gtable       0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  htmltools    0.3.6      2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  knitr        1.19       2018-01-29 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  labeling     0.3        2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                  
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                  
#>  magrittr   * 1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                  
#>  memoise      1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  methods    * 3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  munsell      0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  pillar       1.1.0      2018-01-14 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  pkgconfig    2.0.1      2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  plyr         1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  purrr        0.2.4      2017-10-18 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                  
#>  R6           2.2.2      2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  Rcpp         0.12.15    2018-01-20 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  rlang        0.1.6.9003 2018-02-08 Github (tidyverse/rlang@616fd4d)
#>  rmarkdown    1.8        2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  rprojroot    1.3-2      2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  scales       0.5.0.9000 2018-01-15 Github (hadley/scales@d767915)  
#>  stats      * 3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  stringi      1.1.6      2017-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                  
#>  stringr      1.2.0      2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  tibble       1.4.2      2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  tools        3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  utils      * 3.4.1      2017-06-30 local                           
#>  withr        2.1.1.9000 2018-01-15 Github (jimhester/withr@df18523)
#>  yaml         2.1.16     2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
```

Created on 2018-02-09 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: can you post your version of the libraris?

Comment: @user3022875 I have edited my answer to also contain session info.
There might indeed be a bug in `ggpubr::ggarrange` because if you use `nrow = 1`, the code doesn't work. But `cowplot::plot_grid` doesn't have issues.